# amazon_flex_pay gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the amazon_flex_pay gem for my project. My project based on Selfstarter - open source project.
How I can charge via api gems use the token options?

in documentation

`AmazonFlexPay.pay('12.99', 'USD', 'STOKEN', 'myrequest3292')`
and what is STOKEN?
I put the token_id and see `Sender token is not valid.`
link to the gem - https://github.com/kickstarter/amazon_flex_pay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I haven't used `amazon_flex_pay` yet; I've just been reading up on it. And I haven't used FPS itself in a while.*

The [gem documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/amazon_flex_pay/AmazonFlexPay/API#pay-instance_method) links to the [API documentation for Pay](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAdvancedGuide/Pay.html), which describes the flow in more detail.

The Pay method itself is for actually charging someone money. Before you can do that, you'll need to be authorized by the person paying—the Sender.

To do that, you'll need to use the Co-Branded Service API to sent the user to a (co-branded) Amazon page where they'll confirm their payment. In Selfstarter, this happens at the end of [`OrdersController#prefill`](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter/blob/master/app/controllers/preorder_controller.rb#L10).

If the user agrees, Amazon will post to your application with confirmation, including a **Sender Token**. That Sender Token is your authorization to transfer money from the Sender. In Selfstarter, the action Amazon posts to is [`OrdersController#postfill`](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter/blob/master/app/controllers/preorder_controller.rb#L36). Most of the real work happens in [`Order.postfill!`](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter/blob/master/app/models/order.rb#L25). (Notice that the `tokenID` parameter is saved, as `@order.token`.)

Once you have that token, you can call `AmazonFlexPay.pay` as you have, providing the token you received in place of `'STOKEN'`.

Comment: THanks @Peeja, any idea where I might get the 'token'? I've tried using the Amazon AWS Access+Secret keys and they didn't work unfortunetly.

Comment: The token is the Sender Token, as described in the answer.